# Any plugin related to tracking URLs?

Tags: magento2, social-buttons

Is there any extension related to tracking website URLs? URL can be shared via Whatsapp to customers, which can further be tracked how many opened the link and how many opened via WhatsApp or some other source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Analytics or Google Tag Manager which is embedded in Vanilla Magento2.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/google-universal-analytics.html

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/google-tag-manager.html